# OFX Import in GNUCash suddenly not working anymore

Tags: gnucash

I have not changed my process to generate my OFX file from my bank's pdf+csv.
It worked fine last month.

This time, when I try to import my ofx file, GNUCash asks me to match the account again for some reason and then does not open the transaction-matching screen without giving me anything to look into.

I know that the file is properly formed and contains transactions.

Has something changed in the 4.6+ (2021-06-26) version that I have missed ?
How can I see the logs to understand why it fails ?

Comment: gnucash has a mailing list.

Comment: You could try to ask on the [gnucash-user mailing list](https://lists.gnucash.org/mailman/listinfo/gnucash-user).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the technical issues of a software.